# Stream encountered HTTP error: 403. I'm a beginner at pyspark and python, I can't revise the code

Tags: python, api, pyspark, twitter

1. I know that twitter released `apiv2` and that's a cause I got an error but I can't revise the code
2. I'm aware that I have to use `streamingClient` but I don't understand the concept

```
consumer_key    = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token    = ''
access_secret   = ''
class TweetsListener(tweepy.Stream):

    def __init__(self, csocket):
        self.client_socket = csocket

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            msg = json.loads( data )
            print( msg['text'].encode('utf-8') )
            self.client_socket.send( msg['text'].encode('utf-8') )
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True

def sendData(c_socket):
    twitter_stream=TweetsListener(
        consumer_key, consumer_secret,
        access_token, access_secret,
        csocket=c_socket)
    twitter_stream.filter(track=['football'])
```

Comment: This may be a failed authentication issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: @frmbelz: thanks for wanting to edit posts here. If you can, where there is conversational material ("please halp me") please remove it rather than repairing it. Technical writing is an expectation here, and it is helpful to encourage question authors not to treat it as a chatroom where possible.